# Calculadora no python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tive um problema ao tentar fazer uma calculadora em Python, o primeiro código da erro no 'bool' do "UserSelectionSelect". Estou com dúvida na parte de como declarar um método em um dicionário.

```
def Somar(a,b,r):
    return r == a+b
def Mult(a,b,r):
    return r == a*b
def Sub(a,b,r):
    return r == a - b
def Div(a,b,r):
    return r == a / b


print("Calculadora 1.0")
print("1 - Somar\n\n2 - Subtração\n\n3 - Divisão\n\n4 - Multiplicação\n\n ")
Select = int(input())
a = int(input("Digite o 1° Número "))
b = int(input("Digite o 2° Número "))
r = 0
UserSelection =  {1 : Somar(a,b,r),2 : Sub(a,b,r),3 : Div(a,b,r),4 : Mult(a,b,r)}
UserSelection[Select]()

print(r)
```

Também tentei dessa forma, mas ele não recebe os valores "a,b,r".

```
def Somar(a,b,r):
    return r == a+b
def Mult(a,b,r):
    return r == a*b
def Sub(a,b,r):
    return r == a - b
def Div(a,b,r):
    return r == a / b

UserSelection =  {1 : Somar,2 : Sub,3 : Div,4 : Mult}
print("Calculadora 1.0")
print("1 - Somar\n\n2 - Subtração\n\n3 - Divisão\n\n4 - Multiplicação\n\n ")
Select = int(input())
a = int(input("Digite o 1° Número "))
b = int(input("Digite o 2° Número "))
r = 0
UserSelection[Select]()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem vários erros no seu código, posso citar logo de primeira o fato de que o `return` deve receber apenas o valor que deve retornar.

O que você está tentando fazer com o `return r == a+b`, por exemplo, é na verdade retornar se `a + b` é igual a `r`, ou seja, este *statement* retorna um valor booleano (`True`ou `False`).

Depois, quando chamamos a função na linha

```py
UserSelection[Select]()
```

devemos passar os argumentos que são setados como quando definimos a função lá em cima. Para fazer isso, basta adicionarmos os valores necessários dentro dos parênteses e imprimir na tela o resultado dessa chamada da função (que é o valor do `return`).

Este é o código completo:

```py
def Somar(a,b): # Não é necessário o 'r', pois ele está preso no escopo da função
    return a+b # retorno o resultado da operação
def Mult(a,b):
    return a*b
def Sub(a,b):
    return a - b
def Div(a,b):
    return a / b

UserSelection =  {1 : Somar,2 : Sub,3 : Div,4 : Mult}
print("Calculadora 1.0")
print("1 - Somar\n\n2 - Subtração\n\n3 - Divisão\n\n4 - Multiplicação\n\n ")
Select = int(input())
a = int(input("Digite o 1° Número "))
b = int(input("Digite o 2° Número "))

r = UserSelection[Select](a, b) # Chamamos a função com os argumentos e atribuímos para r
print('A resposta é:', r)
```

Answer (score -1):

Nesse código acima o resultado aparece, mas os números inseridos para a operação matemática, desaparecem ficando assim o resultado final:

Digite o 1º Número:
Digite o 2º Número:
A resposta é: 40

Neste caso foi escolhido a operação soma, foi inserido o número 20 no primeiro número e, 20 no segundo número.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).